# Weird indefinite integral homework questions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm solving a couple of integration problems using the method of changing variables, and would like assistance with two particular problems that I can't seem to solve. I completed rest of the problems in this problem set without much effort, but these two seem impossible.

I've tried changing a few different variables in both problems, and I tried to calculate the solution with Wolfram Alpha, but neither of those had any avail.

$$\int x^{e^{x^2}}~dx$$

and

$$\int\frac{dx}{x+\ln^2x}$$

are the problems that I'm trying to solve. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: They are not solvable in terms of elementary functions. And this is not a hint, it's a fact. However, I'll have some fun in writing possible approaches in a while!

Comment: @KimPeek. I wonder if they could be expressed in terms of **any** function.

Comment: Are you really supposed to find the anti-derivatives?

Comment: @adjan Yes. They're both part of a 20 question problem set. "Integrate the following by the method of changing variables" is what the question says.

Comment: @rob1194 Are those exercises taken from a specific book or from lecture notes?

Answer (score 1):

**This should be a comment, but it would be too long for the comments section, so I'll write it here. Please do not vote up / down unless you find I wrote a real malarkey. In that case, I'll provide to delete this or to improve it.**

As we said in the comments, there are no expressions in terms of simple and elementary functions, and also most probably there are no answers in terms of any functions, as @Claude Leibovici stated.

The other problem is that your integrals are undefined, so either numerical approaches are available. I'll provide to show you some substitutions to make things clearer.

**1**

In this integral you might naively try the substitution

$$e^{x^2} = t ~~~~~ x^2 = \ln(t) ~~~~~ x = \sqrt{\ln(t)} ~~~~~ \text{d}t = 2t\ \sqrt{\ln(t)}$$

gaining

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\ \frac{(\ln(t))^{t/2 - 1/2}}{t}\ \text{d}t$$

and since it involves the form $t^{-1}[F(t)]^t$ the possibilities it can be integrated are like zero. I don't think one may find a more suitable expression (despite the fact it makes me to think about the Logarithmic Integral Special Function, but it's more complex since it has a $t$ in the exponent itself).

**2**

For this one, it could be good to use (for $t > 0$)

$$x = e^t ~~~~~~~ \text{d}x = e^t\ \text{d}t$$

to get

$$\int\frac{e^t}{e^t + t^2}\ \text{d}t$$

We may collect the $e^t$ factor to have

$$\int\frac{\text{d}t}{1 + t^2e^{-t}}$$

Which **could be** treated in several ways, **if** the integral had extrema. Having not, we cannot say that much.

Notice also that this substitution works for $t > 0$ only, so other possible ways are opened.

Comment: Huh. Well we haven't even mentioned nonelementary integrals in class, so I suppose I'll just skip the questions.

Thank you for taking the time to write the answer. :)

Comment: @rob1194 You're welcome! Please, I'm really curious about. Try to ask your professor about those, and let us know!! Were they take from a book? Or from lecture notes?

Comment: Not sure, we just got the worksheet from the school's website. I skimmed through the book and didn't find them. I'll ask about them tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 1):

For $\int x^{e^{x^2}}~dx$ ,

$\int x^{e^{x^2}}~dx$

$=\int e^{e^{x^2}\ln x}~dx$

$=\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{mx^2}\ln^mx}{m!}\right)~dx$

Let $u=\ln x$ ,

Then $x=e^u$

$dx=e^u~du$

$\therefore\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{mx^2}\ln^mx}{m!}\right)~dx$

$=x+\int\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{u^me^ue^{me^{2u}}}{m!}~du$

$=x+\int\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{m^nu^me^{(2n+1)u}}{m!n!}~du$

$=x+\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\dfrac{(-1)^{m-k}m^nu^ke^{(2n+1)u}}{(2n+1)^{m-k+1}n!k!}+C$ (can be obtained from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)

$=x+\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\dfrac{(-1)^{m-k}m^nx^{2n+1}\ln^kx}{(2n+1)^{m-k+1}n!k!}+C$

For $\int\dfrac{dx}{x+\ln^2x}$ ,

Let $u=\ln x$ ,

Then $x=e^u$

$dx=e^u~du$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{dx}{x+\ln^2x}=\int\dfrac{e^u}{e^u+u^2}~du$

Case $1$: $u^2e^{-u}\leq1$ , i.e. $\dfrac{\ln^2x}{x}\leq1$

Then $\int\dfrac{e^u}{e^u+u^2}~du$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{1+u^2e^{-u}}~du$

$=\left(1+\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nu^{2n}e^{-nu}\right)~du$

$=u+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n)!u^ke^{-nu}}{n^{2n-k+1}k!}+C$ (can be obtained from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)

$=\ln x+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n)!\ln^kx}{n^{2n-k+1}k!x^n}+C$